# gcd = 1 when no common numbers

Tags: math, greatest-common-divisor

16 (which has a prime decomposition of 2^4) and 27 (which has a prime decomposition of 3^3) have no common prime factors. Then why is the result of `gcd(16, 27) == 1`?

I've checked with Python:

```
>>> from fractions import gcd
>>> gcd(16, 27)
1
```

Comment: Questions about the mathematical definition of gcd are off topic for stack overflow. That being said, perhaps you are confusing the [greatest common denominator](http://www.math.com/school/subject1/lessons/S1U3L2GL.html) with the [least common multiple](http://www.math.com/school/subject1/lessons/S1U3L3GL.html).

Comment: Yes? Sorry! I was doing a script in Python... I've seen the links and I'm not confused; the Greatest Common Divisor (16, 27) haven't common divisors. Wikipedia: "In mathematics, the greatest common divisor (gcd), also known as the greatest common factor (gcf)"

Comment: As the numbers are co-prime they do not have a common factor. From the wikipedia page GCD(x,y) is the largest positive integer that divides the numbers without a remainder. 1 is the largest number which divides both 16 and 27.

Comment: Thank you Salix :). It could be that 2 numbers haven't common divisors and they aren't coprimes? For example, 6 (2^3) and 27 (3^3) aren't coprimes, and they haven't gcd (no common divisors). What would be the result?

Comment: 6 is 2*3 so GCD(6,27) is 3. Looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-prime Being co-prime is equivalent to their greatest common divisor being 1.

Comment: @BillJoe Your comment below references "bigge[r] numbers".  Are you trying to reimplement a `gcd` function?  You should look into the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are probably confusing with is that the numbers 16 and 27 don't have any common divisors except 1. **GCD is defined as the greatest common divisor/factor which divides both the numbers.**

You are probably thinking about co-primes! But, neither 16 or 27 is prime to be checked for co-prime, as only prime numbers are compared for co-prime condition!

As you can see, the factors (divisors) of 16 are 1,2,4,8,16. Similarly, the factors (divisors) of 27 are 1,3,9,27.

```
16---> 1,2,4,8,16

27---> 1,3,9,27.
```

So, checking the **`highest/greatest common factor(h/gcf)`** OR **`greatest common divisor(gcd)`** of both the numbers, we find the gcd to be 1.

Hence, your python script is giving you the correct result as really the gcd of 16 and 27 does come out to be 1 as I explained above!

Comment: Ouch, with the gcd I must check more combinations. For biggest numbers will be a hell. Ok, thanks a lot!